# How to fetch mutiple images from express api's into react application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I am using mern stack to program an application. I used multer package with express for file uploading and uploaded images in a directory in node.js application. Now i want to fetch the image from that directory. How can i do this? I have found 
`res.sendFile()`
 but there are cases when i will need to fetch multiple files from server at once.  I also have found just sending path from api to react and serving from a folder into react which i don't find secure? how do i go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using streams for my problem the following snippet might come in handy for some one with similar issue.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const stream = require('stream')

app.get('path',(req, res) => {
  const r = fs.createReadStream('path to file') // or any other way to get a readable stream
  const ps = new stream.PassThrough() // <---- this makes a trick with stream error handling
  stream.pipeline(
   r,
   ps, // <---- this makes a trick with stream error handling
   (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err) // No such file or any other kind of error
      return res.sendStatus(400); 
    }
  })
  ps.pipe(res) // <---- this makes a trick with stream error handling
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should decouple the back end from the front end, which means, separate the express part from the React part and make simple API, express also can serve files as static(search google for static file serving), then call the API from your React App. Just give the React App Image URL like example.com/static/image1.png(`<img src={"example.com/static/image1.png"} />`)

Comment: I don't know but serving dynamic user only images as public might not seem like a good idea mate.